# Why can't my vuejs component's mounted hook reference some methods from the same component?

Tags: vue.js, lifecycle

I have a Vue js component. The mounted hook can call some methods and not others. For example, my mounted hook can call the printSomething() method, but not showLayers().

```
  mounted() {
      this.printSomething()
      this.showLayers();
  },
  methods: {
    printSomething() {
      console.log("hello world");
    },
    showLayers() {
      var tempSelectedLayers = []; 
      for (var i = 0; i < this.layers.length; i++) {
        var layer = this.layers[i];
        console.log(layer.layerName + ", " + layer.checked);
        if (layer.checked == true) {
          tempSelectedLayers.push(layer);
        }
      }
      eventBus.$emit(
        "showLayers",
        tempSelectedLayers
      );
    },
```

The vue cli displays the error message:

> vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "showLayers": "TypeError: _this.showLayers is not a function"

It is clear from testing my code at a local host url that the showLayers() function is indeed called despite the error message. If I remove the call to showLayers() from the mounted hook, then the desired behavior does not occur. This suggests the error is related to a race condition. If so, how can I resolve this? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not referring to your call to the `showLayers` method in the mounted hook. As you said, the method is being called. The error is referring to this code which also uses the name `showLayers`:

```
      eventBus.$emit(
        "showLayers",
        tempSelectedLayers
      );
```

Check the component that you are emitting to.